# how to rewrite url's in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I am new to cakephp....i am using cakephp1.3.
i want to rewrite all view files to .html extension in cakephp.
Please help me,i am in need

Comment: what? do you want the view .ctp files use .html extension instead, or what?

Comment: yes...i want to for example....if /controller/view/12 is there instead of that i want /controller/view.html

Answer (score 3):

cakephp does not allow you to do that. ctp extension is hard-coded in all the library files. Unless you want to search and replace all the "ctp" reference to "html", its not possible.

But if you want to rewrite the url and append html suffix, then see [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/952/File-extensions)

Comment: ok...but i want to display .html extension in url only...so that users are unable to see the actual path in url...